# Suggested edit review is not helpful

Tags: feature-request, support, suggested-edits, mathjax

As part of the mod tools, there is a tool to review and approve suggested edits. The "review suggested edits" page shows something like below, which is not of much help to review and approve the edit.

[image: screenshot]

It makes more sense, especially on math.se, to show the final form of the post, including the typeset i.e the form it would appear on screen once it has been posted/approved.

This is of more relevance to math.se since most of suggested edits have got to do with some typesetting changes. It is hard to figure out what exactly the changes are and how they affect the post without looking at how they appear on the screen.

I have also posted this question on [meta.math](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2809/reviewing-suggested-edits).

Comment: As I mentioned in meta.math, one possibility might be to add a link to a "preview" page that shows the formatted changes.

Comment: Hmm, maybe not quite a dupe?  You're right that it would be useful to see the proposed edit in its final form rather than showing the tex code (I assume it's tex).

Comment: I agree that it's not a dupe.  The problem isn't that the diff is too noisy as the duplicate question complained about, it's that the diff interferes with the rendering of MathJax. It's also a problem on [the Revisions page](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/58346/revisions), which includes both the removed stuff and the added stuff inline.   The diff ought to break on the MathJax demiters, as well as word boundaries.